# The channel 1 was closed, you can't use it anymore! (AMQP::ChannelClosedError)

Tags: amazon-ec2, monitoring, sensu

I am trying to use sensu framework for monitoring my EC2 instance but unfortunately i am facing one problem of `The channel 1 was closed, you can't use it anymore! (AMQP::ChannelClosedError)`.
The stack of error is posed here also but can figure out what is the solution.
http://www.sand4.info/index.php?q=aHR0cHM6Ly9naXN0LmdpdGh1Yi5jb20vMTQ5MTA0NA%3D%3D

Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution from IRC... I haven't configure graphite in my windows system. I haven't also find any way to configure in windows. What i have done is i have remove the graphite handler and put the default handler at both client and server side.
This is the config.json at server side.

```
{
  "rabbitmq": {    
    "port": 5672,
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "user": "guest",
    "password": "guest",
    "vhost": "/"    
  },
  "redis": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 6379
  },
  "api": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 4567
  },
  "dashboard": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 8080,
    "user": "admin",
    "password": "admin"
  },
   "handlers": {   
    "default": {
       "type": "pipe",
        "command": "ruby C:/sensuServer/sensuserverSSL/stdout.rb",       
         "send_only_check_output": true
     }
  },
  "checks": {
        "b": {
              "command": "ruby C:/sensuServer/sensuserverSSL/stdout.rb",
              "subscribers": [
                "test"
              ],
              "interval": 10,
              "auto_resolve": true
            }
    }   
}
```